# Copying several columns from one worksheet to another dependent on a criteria

Tags: excel, vba

In my experiment, there were 40 participants (each participant had a number - column I in the worksheet), and each participant had a unique number.

In my worksheet, each participant did 2 tests (column type of test).

I need to copy the columns B, C, and D for each test from the worksheet (depicted below) to a different worksheet.

[image]

Those columns need to be copied to a new worksheet where as described below:

[image]

An example for the first test (Dr_Pi_1) Columns A & B are constant; the three next columns are the first participant, afterward the second participant with his relevant 3 columns, etc.

Similarly, another worksheet for the second test is called, in this case - Ju_Pi_2.

[image]

I am pretty new to VBA so what I managed to do is pretty specific, so I would like to generalize it:

```
Sub Macro5()
    
    x = 1
    Row_increase = 0
    Column_increase = 0
    For x = 1 To 40
        Sheets("Relevant Data").Select
        Range(Cells(2 + Row_increase, 2), Cells(91 + Row_increase, 4)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Drops_PIC_Data").Select
        Cells(2, 3 + Column_increase).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Relevant Data").Select
        Cells(2 + Row_increase, 9).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Drops_PIC_Data").Select
        Range(Cells(1, 3 + Column_increase), Cells(1, 5 + Column_increase)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Row_increase = Row_increase + 181
        Column_increase = Column_increase + 3
        
    Next x
End Sub
```